# append A then B to each number in an array

Tags: php

i have this function in my class

```
    public function createPeriods($numPeriods){
    $numPeriods = ($numPeriods*2);
}
```

numPeriods will always equal either 5 or 6.
I need to split each period into halves and append the letter A to the first half and B to the second half. My desired outcome would look like this if there were 5

```
periods($numPeriods = '5';): 
"1A,1B,2A,2B,3A,3B,4A,4B,5A,5B"
```

Comment: Your title doesn't describe what you want at all. You're appending `A` and `B` to all numbers.

Comment: unless im missing something about my title, it is exactly what i need. To append the letter A to even numbers, and the letter B to the odd numbers. not sure how else to ask the question honestly

Comment: is 2 odd or even? In your example you add A and B to it - i'm confused?

Comment: post edit - yup that makes sense now.

Comment: ahh i understand the confusion in my question now. ive updated the question for clarity. I apologize for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple for loop is needed:

```
public function createPeriods($numPeriods){
    $periods = array()
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $numPeriods; $i++) {
        $periods[] = $i.'A';
        $periods[] = $i.'B';
    }
    return $periods
}
```

The `createPeriods` function will output an array of your periods. To output a string separated by a comma you can use `echo implode(',', createPeriods(5));`

Answer (score 0):

No need to test odd and even numbers, just add both of them to the results in a loop.

```
public function createPeriods($numPeriods) {
    $results = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $numPeriods; $i++) {
        $results[] = $i . 'A';
        $results[] = $i . 'B';
    }
    return implode(',', $results);
}
```